# Inserting array into a hashmap with counter

Tags: java, arrays, count, insert, hashmap

So I am having some difficulties understanding this code. The for-each inputs the strings from the array along with a counter that counts over the number of identical strings, but how does the counter do this?

What is the number that gets passed to counter at: `Integer count = map.get(nextString);`

And what do the if-statements do?

```
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String nextString : inArray) {

        Integer count = map.get(nextString);

        if (count == null) {

        count = 1;

        } else {

        count = count + 1;

        }

        map.put(nextString, count);

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Do you know how a java HashMap works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

This is just initialising our HashMap, nothing complex.

```
for (String nextString : inArray) {

    Integer count = map.get(nextString);
```

Here we are looking for the *value* associated with our *key* (in this case a String from our array).

```
    if (count == null) {

        count = 1;
```

Because we are updating the map with the number of times a given string occurs, if there is *no* value associated with our key then this string hasn't been counted yet, so we set `count` to 1 because it's the first occurrence of this String in our array.

```
    } else {

        count = count + 1;
```

If the above if-statement didn't execute, that means there is some value associated with the string, so we can just increment it then put it back in the map.

```
    }

    map.put(nextString, count);

}
```

Comment: Please fix the lazy identation, instead just copying that messy style used by the OP.